# How to change the Firebase Cloud function URL?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cloudflare, firebase-hosting

If we create a firebase function with `onRequest` trigger, the URL will be autogenerated based on the following things:

```
 1. The region (or regions) to which you deployed your function
 2. Your Firebase project ID
 3. cloudfunctions.net
 4. The name of your function
```

So the end result will looks like this: `https://<region>-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/<function name>`

The issue is that now we want to connect Cloudflare to the website and need to change the endpoint URL to something like this: `https://<cloudflare-subdomain>.<website-domain>/<function name>`. Could you please advise how to do that?

I've already tried this - [firebase direct requests to a function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrite-functions)

But as far as I understand, it will allow rewriting URLs in the same domain, so we cannot add the `cloudflare subdomain` into the path...

Comment: What do you mean by Cloudflare subdomain? If you own the domain you can just setup that with Firebase hosting custom domains and then use rewrites as in the documentation.

Comment: Does above comment helped you?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the thought. I am not sure yet if it will help. I will check and let you know

Comment: By Cloudflare subdomain, I mean a subdomain that you can specify when connecting a site domain to Cloudflare. In our case, we want to add that, to have a different endpoint for prod and staging

Comment: One thing to clarify:
In the documentation link that I specified in the description, firebase says the following: 
```
You can use rewrites to serve a function from a Firebase Hosting URL.
For example, to direct all requests from the page /bigben on your Hosting site to execute the bigben function
```

Do you think it will work if I want to request the URL as an endpoint? Like saving the data or some other action. So not when a page is opened on site, just to request as usual API URL

Comment: I believe it is possible as you can connect [sub domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55572871/18265570) in `firebase`. check this document [1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain#set-up) &[2](https://afrimadonidinata.medium.com/how-to-use-custom-sub-domain-for-your-firebase-hosting-9472ce516969#:~:text=Connect%20Sub%20Domain,on%20%E2%80%9CConnect%20Domain%E2%80%9D%20button.&text=Enter%20you%20subdomain%20into%20popup,mydomain.com%20then%20click%20continue.)